# tikz intersection of named path

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I want to use named path to calculate the intersection of 2 line. but below example code doesn't work!

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={\tiny #1},name=#1},
}

\node[dot=A] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\node[dot=C] (C) at (0,1) {};
\node[dot=D] (D) at (1,0.5) {};

\path[name path=P1] (A) -- (B);
\path[name path=P2] (C) -- (D);

\coordinate (CS) at (intersection of P1 and P2); 
%\coordinate (CS) at (intersection of A--B and C--D); 

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (C) -- (D);
\node[dot=E] (E) at (CS) {};
\draw[dotted] (B)--(E)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I use the comment out line as below:

```
\coordinate (CS) at (intersection of A--B and C--D);
```

It works fine. Is it possible to use a named path as argument of intersection macro!

Expected output as below:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a real intersection you can write (I changed the coordinates of D)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={\tiny #1},name=#1}}
\node[dot=A] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\node[dot=C] (C) at (0,1) {};
\node[dot=D] (D) at (1,-0.5) {};

\draw [name path=P1] (A) -- (B);
\draw [name path=P2] (C) -- (D);

\path [name intersections={of=P1 and P2,by=E}];
\node[dot=E]  at (E) {};
\draw[dotted] (B)--(E)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

else

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={\tiny #1},name=#1}}
\node[dot=A] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\node[dot=C] (C) at (0,1) {};
\node[dot=D] (D) at (1,0.5) {};

\draw [name path=A--B] (A) -- (B);
\draw [name path=C--D] (C) -- (D);

\coordinate (E) at (intersection of A--B and C--D);
\node[dot=E]  at (E) {};
\draw[dotted] (B)--(E)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Most of the case, user didn't know where is the intersection. so we wish the second solution better. That means in my case, we can not use path to simplify our code! :-)

Comment: @lucky1928 I agree with you but sometime we must adapt ...

Comment: Could you edit to make clear that only the first code is supported by current Ti*k*Z and only the second by version 2? This is causing some confusion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384673/tikz-intersections-why-one-of-the-methods-does-not-work. (I'm assuming this explanation is correct, based on the comments. Please accept my apologies if I'm mistaken.)

Answer (score 10):

There must be a real intersection between path `P1` and path `P2`. You could use something like

```
\path[name path=P1,overlay] (A) -- (B)--([turn]0:5cm);
\path[name path=P2,overlay] (C) -- (D)--([turn]0:5cm);
```

to enlarge the paths without enlarging the bounding box of the picture.

Then you can use

```
\path [name intersections={of=P1 and P2,by={CS}}];
```

to define a coordinate `CS` at the intersection of the enlarged paths `P1` and `P2`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={\tiny #1},name=#1},
}

\node[dot=A] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\node[dot=C] (C) at (0,1) {};
\node[dot=D] (D) at (1,0.5) {};

\path[name path=P1,overlay] (A) -- (B)--([turn]0:5cm);
\path[name path=P2,overlay] (C) -- (D)--([turn]0:5cm);

\path [name intersections={of=P1 and P2,by={CS}}];

\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (C) -- (D);
\node[dot=E] (E) at (CS) {};
\draw[dotted] (B)--(E)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had never seen `turn` before. Nice trick! Thank you!

Comment: Yes very fine remark ! in   13.4.2 Rotational Relative Coordinates

Comment: @AlainMatthes Cool, but if I remove the turn, the result is totally wrong. why? I didn't find such section in my pgfmanual, is it a latest version change?

Answer (score 6):

Notation `intersection of A--B and C--D` is old and doesn't appear in `TikZ 3.0` documentation.

New `intersections` library is documented in section "13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths" where is explained how to use `named paths`.

In your particular case the problem is that paths `P1` and `P2` doesn't intersect because they are too short. You can make them longer with `calc` library help and syntax explained in "13.15.3 The Syntax of Partway Modiﬁers" which defines points on line between two coordinates but not necessarily in between.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={\tiny #1},name=#1},
}

\node[dot=A] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\node[dot=C] (C) at (0,1) {};
\node[dot=D] (D) at (1,0.5) {};

\path[name path=P1] (A) -- ($(A)!3!(B)$);
\path[name path=P2] (C) -- ($(C)!3!(D)$);

\path [name intersections={of=P1 and P2, by={E}}];
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (C) -- (D);
\node[dot=E] at (E) {};
\draw[dotted] (B)--(E)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the pgfmanual pgf 3.01 page 61 you have `\path [name intersections={of=A--B and C--C’,by=F}];` but with `\draw [name path=A--B] (A) -- (B);
` before.

Comment: @AlainMatthes Example on page 61 doesn't use syntax `intersection of A--B and C--D` (no equal sign, no `name intersections`) which was valid in earlier `TikZ` versions (see comments in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290502/1952)