# Tikz intersections: Why one of the methods does not work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[name=w, rectangle, fill=darkgray, minimum width=3mm, minimum height = 6cm]{};
    \path[name path=wnw] (w.north west)--++(-6, 0);
    \path[name path=wv] (w.west)--++(128:6);
    \path [name intersections={of=wnw and wv, by={B}}];
    \draw (w.west)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Question**

Why the below approach does not work? (I get "undefined node" error.)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[name=w, rectangle, fill=darkgray, minimum width=3mm, minimum height = 6cm]{};
    \path[name path=wnw] (w.north west)--++(-6, 0);
    \path[name path=wv] (w.west)--++(128:6);
    \coordinate (B) at (intersection of wnw and wv);
    \draw (w.west)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work? Is that syntax documented somewhere?

Comment: @Torbjørn Looking at this answer, I was hoping it would work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299185/48787

Comment: Well, strictly speaking that syntax isn't documented (in the current manual) either. It was in version 2.0 though, before the introduction of the `intersection` library and `name path`. (If you're interested, download the source from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%202.00/, find `pgfmanual.pdf` in `doc/generic/pgf/`, and look in section 12.2.4.) I would think that it doesn't work because it's not intended to work, but I don't know anything about the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second example uses a [deprecated syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299181/1952) previous to `intersections` library, but it still works if you uses it correctly. The concept of `named path` doesn't exist and path are identified by two coordinates each one: `A--B`. Coordinates without parenthesis.

In your case, it's possible to write a path with `w.north west--{++(-6,0)}` where brackets hide the second coordinate parenthesis.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[name=w, rectangle, fill=darkgray, minimum width=3mm, minimum height = 6cm]{};
    \path (w.north west)--++(-6, 0);
    \path (w.west)--++(128:6);
    \coordinate (B) at (intersection of w.north west--{++(-6,0)} and w.west--{++(128:6)});
    \draw (w.west)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]