# How can I compile TikZ pgf manuals 1.01; 1.18; 2.10 and 3.0.1a?

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, texlive

My request to archive old TikZ manuals was closed on the grounds that it is sufficient to compile these manuals with the corresponding version of pgf.

[Archive old manuals? #903](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/903#issue-671555153)

It is specified that to do this, it is necessary to compile with the [corresponding version of pgf](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/903#issuecomment-667637618).

How do you go about compiling an old manual on `MikTeX` in practice? On [TeX Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live)?

The pgf tikz repository only keeps [the sources](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases).

Comment: this seems a very strange thing to want to do. If you just want to look at the old pdfs they are available in texlive svn, but what is the use of an old manual anyway?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem is specific to TikZ. There are some macros which have been documented in old TikZ manuals and which are no longer documented since version 3.0.0. These macros are still used and to understand their syntax it is necessary to read the old manuals. See for example this question: [What do "-to" and "pre = moveto" do in TikZ arrows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555655/138900) and the comment dated `Feb 1 '16 at 9:14` from Ulrike here [Specifying the point via “intersection of” in TikZ - a problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290502/138900)

Answer (score 8):

To compile a previous version of the pgf manual as a whole you can perform the following steps:

1. Clone the git repository: `git clone https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf`
2. Checkout the tag you want to compile the manual for (you can list the tags using `git tag`). I'll do that for `3.0.1` by running `git checkout 3.0.1`.
3. Configure an RCS provider script like https://github.com/kimmormh/git-rcs-keywords or replace the `$Header$` by `$Header: x.y,v z 2020/01/01 a$` with something along the lines of `find ./ -exec sed -i 's=\$Header\$=\$Header: x.y,v z 2020/01/01 a\$=g' {} \;`.
4. Create a texmf directory `mkdir -p texmf/tex` and `cp -r {context,generic,latex,plain} texmf/tex`.
5. Create an auxiliary tree using `sudo tlmgr conf auxtrees add "$(pwd)/texmf"`
6. Change into the engine's folder you want to compile the manual with. I will use pdftex, so I do `cd doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en`.
7. Run `make` in this folder.
8. Open the generated PDF.

Comment: As I understand it, this only works on Linux?

Comment: @AndréC I only have Linux so I can't test. But probably also on Mac OS and on Windows you can use the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), I guess.