# Where can we find the old TikZ and pgf manuals?

Tags: tikz-pgf

A number of operations and options introduced in the early versions of TikZ are no longer documented but are still used and useful.

For example, the syntax used in this question [Specifying the point via "intersection of" in TikZ - a problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290502/138900) which is :

```
(intersection of a--b and c--d)
```

is no longer documented since version 3.0.

Ulrike Fischer asks the same question to Percusse in a comment on  [Feb 1 '16 at 9:19](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290502/specifying-the-point-via-intersection-of-in-tikz-a-problem#comment702990_290502), I quote:

> @percusse: Is this use of intersection of X and Y documented
> somewhere? I can find the documentation of the library and named path
> but nothing else.

Old code can be found everywhere on the net and the latest manuals do not always explain the syntax used.

The purpose of this question is to archive and to be able to quickly find old manuals.

Translated from **french** with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: What exactly was translated by DeepL?

Comment: @pluton Everything is translated with deepl.com the title of the question and the question itself and the answer. I say this because automatic translators, although they translate better than I do, can still make syntax errors.

Comment: but where is the original question? In which language?

Comment: I asked the question and answered it myself.

Comment: It would then be nice to indicate the original language: Translated from <language> with DeepL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All TikZ and PGF manuals are available in the TeX Live SVN repository.

- [Repository from versions 2 and 3](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?view=log)
- [Repository for versions 1.](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en/pgfmanual.pdf?view=log&pathrev=6740)

## TikZ and PGF version 3.1

- 2 Oct 2020 [Manual for Version 3.1.6a](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=56512&view=co)
- 28 Sep 2020 [Manual for Version 3.1.6](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=56462&view=co)
- 8 Jan 2020 [Manual for Version 3.1.5b](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=53349&view=co)
- 21 Dec 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.5a](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=53202&view=co)
- 19 Dec 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.5](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=53187&view=co)
- 4 Aug 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.4b](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=51817&view=co)
- 17 Jul 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.4a](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=51667&view=co)
- 12 Jul 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.4](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=51626&view=co)
- 12 May 2019  [Manual for Version 3.1.3](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=51107&view=co)
- 8 May 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.1](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=51047&view=co)
- 5 May 209 [Manual for Version 3.1.2](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=51018&view=co)
- 8 Apr 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.2](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=50867&view=co)
- 4 Apr 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.2](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=50758&view=co)
- 2 Feb 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1.1](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=49907&view=co)
- 5 Jan 2019 [Manual for Version 3.1](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=49607&view=co)

## TikZ and PGF version 3.0

- 29 Aug 2015 [Manual for Version 3.0.1a](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=38237&view=co)
- 8 Aug 2015 [Manual for Version 3.0.1](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=38079&view=co)
- 27 Feb 2014 [Manual for version 3.0.0](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=33057&view=co)

## TikZ and PGF version 2

- 29 Oct 2010 [Manual for version 2.10](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=20236&view=co)
- 30 May 2009 [Manual for version 2.00](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=13530&view=co)
- 23 Feb 2008 [Manual for version 2.00](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=6741&view=co)

## TikZ and PGF version 1

- 17 Jun 2007 [Manual for version 1.18](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=4459&view=co&pathrev=6740)
- 3 Nov 2003 [Manual for version 1.10](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=2382&view=co&pathrev=6740)
- 15 Oct 2006 [Manual for version 1.09](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=2332&view=co&pathrev=6740)
- 4 Oct 2006 [Manual for version 1.01](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=2240&view=co&pathrev=6740)
- 9 Jan 2006 [Manual for Version 1.00](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-pdftex/en/pgfmanual.pdf?revision=85&view=co&pathrev=6740)

Comment: For other packages, they're all in https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/generic/ but look for the correct folder/version number can be annoying.